# VBA for loop with negative step, k, calling array(k+1). What will it do?

Tags: arrays, vba

```
For k = kT To 0 Step -1
ThKC(k + 1) = ThKCl
.
.
.
next k
```

Suppose I have kT as 5000. ThkCl is a constant value. During the first iteration when I say (k+1), what will be the index of ThKC array?

I have no idea about VBA and need a script changed to python. So I'm just looking for the logic in the script. I also have the same script in Fortran90 too, but VBA seemed easier to understand. Any tips on the migration are also welcome.

Comment: The first time through the loop `k` will be 5000, so the index will be 5001.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, that what you have in mind could be:

```vb
kT = 5000

For k = kT To 0 Step -1
    ThKC(k) = ThKCl
    ' Do other tasks.
Next
```

That would loop from 5000 to 0.

Comment: I thought so too, but they have called (k+1) in all the places so it might be that they are trying to assign values one row above the current row.

Comment: Well, who knows? That's why decent programmers include in-line comments to explain "weird" code.